# How to create a search displaying all tickets that have been created between certain dates

Tags: jira

For security purposes I am looking for a way to show all the tickets for a particular project between time x and y.

If I change the url a bit I can get to something like this:

```
https://contexta.atlassian.net/browse/ISO-77?jql=created%20%3E%3D%20-4w%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20ASC
```

Which gives me the last 4 weeks of all project but I have a hard time finding out how the syntax should be exactly. Anybody who can show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jql which is better but you may add this.

```
?jql=project%20%3D%20<project code>%20AND%20createdDate%20<%3D%202019-07-01%20AND%20createdDate%20<%202019-07-31
```

JQL is

```
project = <project code> AND createdDate <= 2019-07-01 AND createdDate < 2019-07-31 ORDER BY updated DESC
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! But what to do if I want to chain this with a certain project. So lets say I reach my project tickets via: https://contexta.atlassian.net/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=26&projectKey=SEC. How can I combine these 2?#

Comment: I modify my answer.